# How to mask **some** of the previous tokens in causal language model training?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, tokenize, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I'm following [this tutorial](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter7/6) on training a causal language model from scratch. My dataset is a corpus of text:

```
my_dataset = ["some_text... _112_ some_text... _113_ some_text... _114_ some_text...", "some_text... _1423_ some_text... _1424_ some_text... _1425_ some_text...", "some_text... _1111_ some_text... _1111_ some_text... _1111_ some_text..."].
```

The issue is that my dataset contains a clear pattern of numbers in each text (either the numbers are consecutive or they repeat).

**I would like to mask out the previous predicted numbers in this pattern as the model predicts the next tokens** (note that they always has the pattern of `_X_`, where `X` is a number, so I don't want to just mask out any previous number, but just those that correspond to the pattern).

For example, given the first text, after the model predicts `_112_`, I'd like to mask the number `112` in that sequence for the subsequent token predictions (e.g., `"some_text... _MaskToken_ some_text..."`).

I found [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60969176/training-huggingfaces-gpt2-from-scratch-how-to-implement-causal-mask) that I believe asked a similar question a couple of years ago, but left unanswered and used an inefficient method therefore. From the tutorial I'm using it seems like the [DataCollatorForLanguageModeling](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/data_collator) collator might be the way to go about this:

> "Besides stacking and padding batches, it also takes care of creating
> the language model labels — in causal language modeling the inputs
> serve as labels too (just shifted by one element), and this data
> collator creates them on the fly during training so we don’t need to
> duplicate the input_ids."

From [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/LanguageTechnology/comments/uyrobu/does_the_datacollatorforlanguagemodelling_class/) I understand that the `DataCollatorForLanguageModelling`

> "Duplicate the training sentence. If the masking is performed every
> time a sequence is fed to the model, the model sees different versions
> of the same sentence with masks on different positions."

The tutorial also mention

> Shifting the inputs and labels to align them happens inside the model,
> so the data collator just copies the inputs to create the labels.

But going over the source code of [GPT2LMHeadModel](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.26.1/src/transformers/models/gpt2/modeling_gpt2.py#L943) or the data collator it is not clear to me how to do this either.